# ZF2 Execute function before child routes that are in some modules

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a route called student, like this

```
'student' => array(
 'type' => 'Hostname',
   'options' => array(
     'route' => ':subdomain.domain.com',
     'constraints' => array(
       'subdomain' => '([a-zA-Z0-9]*)'
         ...
```

And there are child routes in some of my modules. I need to run a function (e.g. checkSubdomain()) before execute any action of this child routes.

Anyone can help me?

Thank you guys! My code now:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, array($this, 'checkSubdomain'));
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
}

public function checkSubdomain(EventInterface $e) {
    $app = $e->getApplication();
    $sm = $app->getServiceManager();
    $routeMatch = $e->getRouteMatch();
    $matchedRouteName = $routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName();


    $arr = explode('/',$matchedRouteName);
    if ($arr[0]=='student') {
        $subdomain = $routeMatch->getParam('subdomain');
        $em = $sm->get('project_entitymanager');
        $proj = $em->getRepository('Project\Entity\Project')->findOneBy(array('subdomain' => $subdomain));

        if (!$proj) $e->stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what actually needs to be done in this 'check', I would attach an event listener to the `MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE` event or perhaps `MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH`

For example

```
// Module.php
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event) {
  $application  = $event->getApplication();
  $eventManager = $application->getEventManager();

  $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, array($this, 'checkSubdomain'));
} 

public function checkSubdomain(EventInterface $event) {
   // Use $event to fetch the required event criteria
   // and 'check' sub domain here
}
```

Comment: Either this or like i've mentioned at FB, create your own route type that does the DB-checking for a valid subdomain-name internally.

Comment: @Sam i don't know how to do that.. But it sounds like the correct way rs

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `Module` class's `init` function.
In `module/Application/Module.php` and `init`